# What does function composition being associative even mean?

Tags: functions, order

When we have a math problem such as `3 + 5 + 2`, we say that it is associative. We can choose which step to pick first: `3 + (5 + 2)`; we know that brackets affect the order in which the operations are performed.

I've learned that **function composition is a binary operation and it is also associative**. They say, function composition is the scenario where an output of one function is used as an input of another; like method chaining.

The problem is that I am struggling to imagine how to combine two functions together. I've seen online a function called `combine` that takes two functions as arguments and then returns the third function that just calls these two functions one after another; but that doesn't affect anything at all. It is just an alias, like if it were `a + b + c` and became `a + d, where d = b + c`. It doesn't affect anything really.

I am not sure what should be even affected in here; obviously it's not **the order in which the functions are executed**, since the execution itself is not a binary operation. **So what is the binary operation in function composition then?** What's the difference between a scenario when we compose two functions together and when we don't?

Comment: Technically, the brackets affect the binding of operators to operands, effectively adjusting their precedence.  That then sometimes influences an ordering of operations, but there are examples where the brackets only partially dictate the order of operations, such as `(3+4)*(5+6)`, where the order of the two additions there remains unspecified by mathematics.

Comment: @ErikEidt, the order there is not so much unspecified. It is more considered undifferentiated and equivalent, due to the commutative property of the addition and multiplication operators. With non-commutative operators, the orders are implicitly defined and fixed.

Comment: @Steve, No, that's bindings/precedence that are implicitly defined and fixed.  The order of evaluation is not implied by the mathematical expression.  In my above, there are two additions, and their order is not defined -- this requires no commutativity and no associativity.  We can add 3 and 4 first or 5 and 6 first, or do them in parallel.  Of course the multiply has to wait for the results of both additions, so there is a partial ordering implied.

Comment: @ErikEidt, ah I think I see what you're saying. Yes, the evaluation order of sub-expressions is only specified insofar as ordering can alter the result. Where there is more than one possible ordering of evaluation of an expression, but it cannot alter the result, mathematics furnishes no syntax to allow such an unnecessary order to be specified.

Comment: "I am struggling to imagine how to combine two functions together" And a definition of "function composition" for binary functions is what?

Comment: Function composition is inherently a mathematical concept. Consider composing (using Haskell syntax)`f = \x -> x + 1` and `g = \x -> x + 2`. There is a third function `h = \x -> x + 3` that is *equivalent* to `f ∘ g`, but most languages can't or won't find this equivalence and "compose" the original two with something like `h' = \y -> f (g y)` instead. Both `h` and `h'` produce the same result, but don't *compute* that result in the same way.

Comment: People don't like the scary `monad` word but it's an excellent, practical example of assiociative function composition: `map(map(array, f), g)` should be equal to `map(array, g ∘ f)` where one may be more readable and the other more performant. You can choose the more readable path while your compiler is free to rewrite your code into something equivalent but faster.

Comment: "What's the difference between a scenario when we compose two functions together and when we don't?" One could ask what the difference between 5+2 and 7 is. The two expressions represent the same value, but one of them gives a number directly while the other gives it as a composition of two other numbers. Function composition is no different.

Comment: @Schmid that's a good example, but it doesn't actually involve any monad (`map` is simply a functor operation).

Comment: But remember, a monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think "functional composition" tends to be a bit confusing.

By "compose" what we mean is piping the output of one function to the input of another.

Most modern programming languages have some facility for evaluating expressions, and we are accustomed to seeing composition occur in the form of `Sqrt(Add(2, 2))`, where the output of 'Add' forms the input for 'Sqrt'.

What's notable about this familiar form of composition is that the operands which form the ultimate input (in this case, a pair of '2's) must also be specified at the same time as the composition. You can use variables in place of literals, but you still have to provide something for the operands, as part of specifying the composition.

However, in functional languages, the *composition operator* allows these two functions to be composed without specifying anything for the operands.

The evaluation of `AddAndSqrt = (Add ∘ Sqrt)` gets the function pointers for both 'Add' and 'Sqrt' (so that these functions are not called in this expression, but instead their *addresses* are evaluated as function pointers, and then these are provided as operands to the composition operator), and returns a new function pointer, which takes two operands (effectively, the inputs to the 'Add' stage), and when called like so `AddAndSqrt(2, 2)`, outputs the same result as would `Sqrt(Add(2, 2))`.

Behind the scenes, the output of the 'Add' stage is arranged so as to be piped to the input of the 'Sqrt' stage. That is what the composition operator does.

Now, composition is an associative operator simply because in the expression `C(B(A(2, 2)))` it doesn't matter whether you pipe A to B (yielding AB) then pipe AB to C (yielding ABC), or pipe B to C (yielding BC) then pipe A to BC (yielding ABC).

Or to put it another way, it doesn't matter if you write:

```
 Result1 = B(A(2, 2))
 Result2 = C(Result1)

 OR

 Result1 = A(2, 2)
 Result2 = C(B(Result1))
```

In both cases, the chain of calls you end up with is equivalent to `C(B(A(2, 2)))`.

That's all it means for the composition operator to be associative.

All "operators" in mathematics have a set of "properties" - like associativity - that concern their behaviour under algebraic rearrangement. That is, concerning whether different kinds of rearrangement within an expression cause the result to change, or whether the result stays the same despite the rearrangement.

Has that answered the question?

**Edit:** a number of commentators have pointed out that the standard convention when using the function composition operator `∘` is that the first-applied argument goes on the right. So that the equivalent of `C(B(A(x,y)))` would be `(C ∘ B ∘ A)(x, y)` in typical functional languages, and certainly so in general mathematics.

However I think that many programmers would readily prefer the idea that the sequencing of operations proceeds in English order left-to-right, so I'm going to leave the main body of the answer as it is.

I was also pleased to find that in F#, composition can be done left to right in accordance with my preference, although using a different symbol for the composition operator (`>>`): https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-composition/

So that `C(B(A(x,y)))` would become `(A >> B >> C)(x, y)`.

Comment: Minor remark to "in functional languages" - I would say this is true in any language which supports functions as "first-class citizens", so a lot of multi-paradigm languages, not just functional languages.

Comment: @DocBrown, agreed.

Comment: There are plenty of interesting points in this answer.  As a side remark,  an important notation issue:  [(f o g)(x) means f(g(x))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).  So `AddAndSqrt` (i.e. taking the output of add as input of sqrt, should be noted `Sqrt o Add`.

Comment: @Christophe, fair point. Although I likes me pseudocode as I likes me English: always left to right!

Comment: @Steve  I think you're just going to end up confusing anybody who's new to this by not using `o` correctly. And anyway, preferences not withstanding,`AddAndSqrt(...)` is still `Sqrt(Add(...))` and not `Add(Sqrt(...))`, so not always left to right.

Comment: In category theory people often use the notation `;` to mean `o` with its operands in the opposite order. So (f;g)(x) = g(f(x)). You can think of f;g as "do f and then do g". But f o g still means f(g(x)) - that convention is pretty much universal.

Comment: @muru, to be honest I didn't even know the order of operands for `∘`. I just copy and pasted the symbol from the question. I could have said `Add COMPOSE Sqrt`, and had the freedom in this imaginary language, but I felt that using the symbol for the operator would be clearer to those who are broadly familiar with the idea that infix operators in mainstream languages tend to be symbols, and that what falls on either side are the arguments. I'll add a note.

Comment: @Steve thanks. Two more things: 1) even if I did see `Add COMPOSE Sqrt`, my first thought would be that it is `Add(Sqrt(...))`, and 2) "infix operators in mainstream languages tend to be symbols, and that what falls on either side are the arguments" all true but somewhat besides the point, which is that what falls on *which* side may matter. `2 ^ 3` may or may not be equal to `3 ^ 2`, depending on what `^` means.

Comment: @muru, (1) yes, but if you weren't already familiar with functional languages, you might not understand that `COMPOSE` is an operator in an expression and that 'Add' and 'Sqrt' are the arguments! It's the use of the symbol which emphasises that it should be parsed as an operator in an expression. Some languages like VB and SQL do have alphabetic operators, but none of these languages with alphabetic operators have functional composition. (2) certainly the order matters, but the ordering is an arbitrary choice of language design, and I've said more on that in the note appended to the answer.

Comment: @Steve (1) not really. People are likely to be familiar with expressions like `A XOR B`, for example; and (2) thanks *again*, but really, just fixing your usage would be easier for everyone.

Comment: Interestingly, the reason that the notation `C(B(A(2, 2)))` even works is exactly the fact that function composition _is_ associative.

Comment: It's not a "convention" that `(f ∘ g)(x) == f(g(x))`; it's the *definition*. If you think that ordering is confusing, fine, but don't redefine a commonly used symbol just because you disagree with its definition; *pick a different symbol*.

Comment: I must add to the voice and say: **please** don't misuse the well-defined composition operator based on what seems more approachable. Others will not do the same and it will just lead to a bigger mess. Now that you have the F# example that actually *does* compose from left to right, you could introduce that up front and use it throughout. I think everyone wins in that scenario.

Comment: @Steve Given that you agree that the definition is completely arbitrary, I don't understand your reluctance to follow established conventions. Someone who hasn't run into the concept and symbol before will have to learn what it means anyhow, but your choice confuses everyone else. And worse: Anyone who learns the concepts here will then be *very* confused when they see the symbol anywhere else.

Comment: @Voo, I think the exact symbol used would be the least of the concerns of those who come to this answer without a clear understanding of composition. I wrote my answer in a pseudo VB syntax using concepts from C, neither of which actually have a function composition operator. With the additional note, and the reference to an F# implementation using a different operator symbol, I don't think there is any particular cause for confusion at all. (1/2)

Comment: And I won't change the ordering because I strongly feel that for programmers who don't already understand this concept of composition, it is most readily explained by having the calls chained left to right, and letting the order of operands be strongly implied by that left to right order. I don't need to write an answer to cater to those with mathematical training who already understand the concept - what they consider a good explanation is often precisely why programmers *don't* understand that explanation. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve As a programmer, I wouldn’t want the first instance of new notation that I encounter to be incorrect and contrary to the established conventions.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo, it wasn't my original intention to introduce any new notation. My answer is quite clear about the existence of the "established convention", and my comments are clear about what I think of it - if we let the average mathematician set the "established conventions" for programmers, we'd be calling our variables x, y, and z.

Answer (score 20):

Function composition doesn't operate on the same arguments as the functions do. If operates *on the functions as arguments*. And since you can designate functions by symbols and invent a (meta-)functor that operates on functions, this meta-construct satisfies the formal definition of associativity: f   ∘ (g    ∘ h) == (f ∘ g) ∘ h.

The fact that you find this obvious, or can't even imagine how it could be otherwise doesn't change this. After all, addition is commutative and most people can't imagine how that could possibly be different either. You have to advance quite far in mathematics (to Hamiltonian quaternions, say) until it's *not* commutative any more.

Comment: When you say "one can invent a (meta-)functor that operates on functions", could you give an example please? I am not sure what are you talking about. But overall it sounds pretty convincing.

Comment: @pro100tom In Java: 
````Predicate<String> startsWithA = (text) -> text.startsWith("A");
Predicate<String> endsWithX   = (text) -> text.endsWith("x");

Predicate<String> startsWithAAndEndsWithX =
        (text) -> startsWithA.test(text) && endsWithX.test(text);
````

Comment: @SirHawrk thanks for the example but where is the `invert` in there?

Comment: @pro100tom: Use the above example as a guideline where you have 3 checks instead of 2 (starts with A, ends with X, contains a Z), and realize that `A && (X && Z) == (A && X) && Z`

Comment: @SirHawk: That's not composition of predicates though, the predicates are composed not with each other but with an intersection operation, and you're looking at associativity of intersection, not of function composition.

Comment: Side note to your quaternion example: addition of quaternions is commutative, **multiplication** isn't. For simple examples of non-commutative groups, I would start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-abelian_group

Comment: matrix multiplication is an elementary example of non-commutativity at work. Also if you define a subtraction operation too

Comment: @qwr also non-associativity, which is what's being talked about. (A - B) - C usually isn't the same as A - (B - C)

Answer (score 10):

Other answers have explained this well in programming terms. But I think it's possible using only familiar mathematical notation, too. Here goes…

Suppose you have three functions: ***f***, ***g***, and ***h***, so that:
   ***f(x)*** = (some function of ***x***)
   ***g(x)*** = (some other function of ***x***)
   ***h(x)*** = (yet another function of ***x***)

(Of course, those are three different ‘***x***’s!)

And suppose that you want to apply them in turn, i.e. to calculate
   ***f(g(h(x)))***
for some ***x***. Or in other words, you want to *compose* the three functions.

To simplify this, let's define a couple of new functions, which I'm going to give the stunningly original names ***fg*** and ***gh***:
   ***let fg(x) = f(g(x))***
and
   ***let gh(x) = g(h(x))***

So we can use them to express our desired result in three different ways:
   ***fg(h(x))***
   ***f(gh(x))***
   ***f(g(h(x)))***

All three of those give the same result (for all values of ***x***). That's because it doesn't matter whether we compose ***f*** and ***g***, and then compose the result with ***h***, *or* we compose ***f*** with the result of composing ***g*** and ***h***; the end result is the same.

I hope you can see the parallel with addition being associative. The above is saying that function composition is associative.

---

(‘Real’ mathematics would write this in a different notation, using the ring operator ‘∘’ to represent function composition:
   ***(f ∘ g) ∘ h = f ∘ (g ∘ h)***
That's simpler and makes the parallel clearer, but of course it's more abstract without the ‘***x***’s, and harder to follow if you're not used to it. But it means exactly the same.)

Comment: This cracks me up! Only a mathematician could possibly think that assigning these functions the arbitrary names f, g, and h, only to then apply them in counter-alphabetical order h, g, f, was a reasonable naming convention! It's actually a brilliant answer for how it illustrates how mathematicians just don't get it - it's like numbering the paragraphs of your instruction booklet Z to A!

Comment: I think you mean gh(x) = g(h(x)) not h(g(x))

Comment: @Steve f,g,h don't necessarily imply any order in composition. Maybe postfix notation like `x h g f` makes more sense (it goes left-to-right, like a unix pipe)

Comment: @user253751 Well done for spotting the, er, deliberate mistake…  %-) Now fixed, ta!

Comment: @qwr, it's precisely my point. Programmers are concerned about rhyme and reason in naming. The naming here is arbitrary but a sequencing is specified. A programmer would most likely choose a naming scheme that accorded with the order of application. When you write a book, the numbering of the chapters is not necessarily meaningful, but you do number things in reading order - no author designates the first chapter of the book Chapter Z, and then progresses through to finish at Chapter A. I know from experience that mathematicians have a blind spot in this area of communication.

Comment: @steve this is why it is refreshing (or makes you think outside the box) when someone is not following convention and versions his software as v3 for the first version, then v3.1 for the second, then v3.14, then v3.141, and you get the idea.

Answer (score 8):

*I'll go straight to the maths where the previous answers didn't dare...*

Saying "function composition is associative" means that you have an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) (which we call "[function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)"). A mathematical operator in general maps one or more elements from some domain(s) onto elements in another domain. In our case, all domains are the [function space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space).

So the composition operator "∘" maps from two functions to a new function. This mapping is defined thus:

- Given `f`, `g` are functions
- then we define `f ∘ g` to be a function as well (to be precise: the operator `∘` maps any two functions onto a function; or in software engineering terms, it creates a function which refers to two other functions)
- and we define `(f ∘ g)(x) := f(g(x))`
- (implicitely and obviously, the domains of `f` and `g` must match to be compatible with each other).

If we now have three functions `f`, `g`, `h`, it makes sense to ask about associvity; i.e. `f ∘ (g ∘ h) =? (f ∘ g) ∘ h`. You can see this easily by substituting the definition:

- `(f ∘ (g ∘ h))(x) = f((g ∘ h)(x)) = f(g(h(x)))`
- `((f ∘ g) ∘ h)(x) = (f ∘ g)(h(x)) = f(g(h(x)))`
- q.e.d.

Comment: And if all the functions have the same domain and codomain, the algebraic structure formed by these function compositions over functions is the [transformation monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup).

Comment: Right! We can _prove_ associativity of function composition ... under very mild hypotheses... not only for "functions mapping sets to sets", but, also, somewhat fancier things... though, indeed, this argument seems to use the fact that functions have inputs, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett, sure, after all we're on softwareengineering.SE, not maths.SE, so I wanted to keep it short and sweet.

Comment: Just a side note on notation, the usual symbol for function composition is a raised circle `∘` (U+2218), not a lowercase `o`. (Depending on your font and/or vision, an `o` maybe easier to read than a `∘`.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner! I tried $\circ$ when I first wrote the answer, but it seems that "latex" math-style is not activated on SWE.SE so I bailed out with the "o" :) . Going right to the proper unicode char is best of course and I have replaced it.

Comment: @AnoE Ah! I'm so used to *not* having LaTeX available on StackOverflow that I don't miss it on other sites (and tend to forget when it is available on sites like math and physics :) ).